# How to change class name on different url angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

Here is my HTML

```
<div class='main-class'>
<div class='step-one'>
</div>
<div class='step-two'>
</div>
<div class='step-three'>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my angularjs script inside the `.run` function

var nextUrl = next.$$route.originalPath;

I want to add active to classes based on url

I tried like this,

```
$rootScope.currentclass = "main-class";
if (nextUrl == '/step-one') {
$rootScope.currentclass = "step-one active";
//change  class name to "step-one active"
}
else if (nextUrl == '/step-two') {
$rootScope.currentclass = "step-one active";
$rootScope.currentclass = "step-two active";
//change  class name to "step-one active" and "step-two active"
}
else if (nextUrl == '/step-three') {
$rootScope.currentclass = "step-one active";
$rootScope.currentclass = "step-two active";
$rootScope.currentclass = "step-three active";
//change  class name to "step-one active" and "step-two active" and "step-three active"
}
else
{
console.log('does nothing');
}
```

But the class name is not changing.. How can i do this ? Help pls

I am not sure i should use `$scope.class = "step-one active"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with ng-class

```
<div class='main-class'>
<div class='step-one' ng-class='{active: currentStep >= 1}'>
</div>
<div class='step-two' ng-class='{active: currentStep >= 2}'>
</div>
<div class='step-three'  ng-class='{active: currentStep >= 3}'>
</div>
</div>
```

and js

```
$rootScope.currentclass = "main-class";
if (nextUrl == '/step-one') {
    $rootScope.currentStep = 1;
}
else if (nextUrl == '/step-two') {
    $rootScope.currentStep = 2;
}
else if (nextUrl == '/step-three') {
     $rootScope.currentStep = 3;
}
else
{
console.log('does nothing');
}
```

Comment: Also, i need to change to "main-class 1" or "main-class 2" accordingly, how can i do this..

Comment: you can do it simply `<div class='main-class' ng-class="currentStep">`

Comment: Thanks Mr.Genius ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about how your app works, I'm going to assume that it is best for you to do this within your controller.

There are some advanced ways to do this, although I will break it down to a beginner level.

**HTML:**

```
<div class='main-class'>
    <div class='step-one' ng-class="{'active': stepOneActive}">One</div>
    <div class='step-two' ng-class="{'active': stepTwoActive}">Two</div>
    <div class='step-three' ng-class="{'active': stepThreeActive}">Three</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript/Angular:**

```
$scope.stepOneActive = false;
$scope.stepTwoActive = false;
$scope.stepThreeActive = false;

if (nextUrl == '/step-one') {
    $scope.stepOneActive = true;
} else if (nextUrl == '/step-two') {
    $scope.stepOneActive = true;
    $scope.stepTwoActive = true;
} else if (nextUrl == '/step-three') {
    $scope.stepOneActive = true;
    $scope.stepTwoActive = true;
    $scope.stepThreeActive = true;
}
```

Basically, the above is setting boolean scope variables based on which URL is visited (I assume you already have the URL capture logic completed already). I then use `ng-class` within the template to check if that specific step should be given then class `active` or not.

**[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/zilions/pen/KzLrNV)**